# MVC 3 Webgrid column to hold image

Tags: jquery, image, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am creating a WebGrid in ASP.NET MVC 3 for the first time and I need to create a column that holds a "star" image.  A user should be able to select on this image which would mean that they have selected it as a favorite. Then, I would have to get the transaction id of that row and save it using jquery.

Any help or examples with syntax would be appreciated. I am not using Razor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with something like this:

```
grid.Column(header: Favorite,
format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("Favorite", "User", new { id = item.Id })" >
<img src="../../Content/Images/favorite.png"
 alt="YourText" title="YourText"
 width:"32px" height="32px"></a></text>)
```